# AJAX Call Returns 301 Error and Stops

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-301

I have an AJAX call working just fine to a PHP script in a file at the root of my web site. Like this:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/addToPicks.php",
        data: {imagePath: theImagePath, clientPath: theClientPath},
        async: true
    });
```

But when I move the addToPicks.php file and then call it like this:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/site/addToPicks.php",
        data: {imagePath: theImagePath, clientPath: theClientPath},
        async: true
    });
```

I get a 301 error and the PHP script does not run.

What must I do to fix the way I'm calling the PHP script?